# Is there a way to specify which extension method to use for extension methods of the same name in different namespaces?

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

A simple example using the code snippet below:

```
using System.Data;
using CustomerNameSpace;
...
...
CDataSet.CustomerDataTable dtCustomer = GetCustomer();

var customersWithName = dtCustomer.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(x => x.Name != null)
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

For some reason, my coworker has created an extension method `CopyToDataTable()` within the `CustomerNameSpace`.

The program in this case is using both namespaces `System.Data` and `CustomerNameSpace`.

Both now contains the extension method `CopyToDataTable()`.

In the sample snippet below, is there a way to specify which extension methods from these two namespaces to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you absolutely need both namespaces in your code, the only way to differentiate is to call the method as a 'normal' static method instead of an extension method:

```
var customers = dtCustomer.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(x => x.Name != null);
CustomerNameSpace.MyExtensionsClass.CopyToDataTable(customers);
```